# Weird behavior of overflow-x

Tags: html, css, overflow

Well, this one is beyond me. I'm not good at CSS, so I can't really 'debug' this one.

I have this SCSS

```css
#container {
  .slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    li.scrolling {
      flex: 0 0 auto;
      min-width: 200px;
      min-height: 100px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul class="slider">
    <li class="scrolling">
      <div class="something"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="scrolling">
      <div class="something2"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="scrolling">
      <div class="something3"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The thing is, every **li** is basically a box contining some text and some links, such that if I click on a link, scrolling the slider "magically" starts to work. 
Otherwise, it just won't scroll. Another thing that makes the scrolling work is to go in developer tools, and meddle with any property whatsoever; after this, I can scroll. It's as if the overflow is stuck, and doing any of these tricks makes it unstuck somehow.

I don't know why this is.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle link?

Comment: @JiiB, it seems to be working like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/f0fyoanz/). Now I'm suspecting it could be a problem in the parent element.

Comment: Here's the parent
`.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
}`

Comment: Additionally, dragging the scrollbar works just fine. The problem is with mouse scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this does **not** exist: `scroll-direction: horizontal;`

But there is a way to archive horizontal scrolling with the scrollwheel, without pressing down the shift key.

I suggest you that a look at this article, it explains the problem very well:
https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/